# How to create a high quality gif with GIMP?

Tags: gimp, gif, image-quality

I'm trying to animate a few images as simple gif. The images contain one human, a red balloon and a green background. The background seems to be dominating. The face is made of only a few colors, and looks pretty ugly.

WIs there a possibility to select certain areas of the image that should be more dominant when auto-generating the color palette?

Comment: Greetings! It would be of great help to us all if you edited your question to include some images. Saves everyone time, and increases the chances that you will get a good answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but those images are private, and the question is pretty generic.

Comment: Without knowledge of the source images it appears to be a bit hard to guide you. Depending on the color range there you probably get better results using a custom palette.

Comment: Well, from your comments I guess GIMP doesn't support the feature I'm searching for. Creating the custom palette would be off topic here... But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick you could try, if you don't feel like building a custom color palette from scratch, would be to make a version of your image with the important elements (like the human and the balloon) scaled much bigger than they'll appear in the finished animation.

You can then convert that image to indexed color (telling GIMP to generate an optimal palette for it) and [import its palette](http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/C/gimp-concepts-palettes.html) into GIMP as a custom palette.  Then just choose that palette when converting your animation to indexed color.